# How to filter an object's properties according to their values?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object called colors,

```js
const colors = {
  green: "yes",
  red: "no",
  yellow: "yes"
};
```

Now, how to get results based on the values. Like, the object should exclude the values which have "no". 
Below is the desired result:

```js
colors = {
  green: "yes",
  yellow: "yes"
};
```

My attempt:

```js
Object.keys(colors).filter(c => { if(colors[c]==="yes"){ return arr4.push(colors)}})
```

Comment: Please also include your attempt.

Comment: Object.keys(colors).filter(c => { if(colors[c]==="yes"){ return arr4.push(colors)}})
Above is what I have tried but its' not what I'm looking for

Comment: As a side note, if your options are 'yes' or 'no', you should probably use `true` and `false` instead to represent boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try formatting your questions for better readability.

You can filter the Object with native JS functions. See below:

```
const colors = {
  green: 'yes',
  red: 'no',
  yellow: 'yes'
}

const filtered = Object.keys(colors)
  .filter(key => colors[key] === 'yes')
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = colors[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

which will return an object

```
{green: "yes", yellow: "yes"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and hopefully easy to understand:

```js
const colors = {
  green: "yes",
  red: "no",
  yellow: "yes",
};

for (const key of Object.keys(colors)) {
  if (colors[key] === "no") {
    delete colors[key];
  }
}
```

That is also a good use case for the new [`fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method. If you feel adventurous, try this instead:

```js
const colors = {
  green: "yes",
  red: "no",
  yellow: "yes",
};

const newColors = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(colors)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value === "yes")
);
```

It has the added benefit of keeping the original object intact, although I find it a bit more difficult to read than my first suggestion.

Comment: This wont work because you cant edit the const colors. Try using let colors = ...

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can (just try the snippet above if you don't believe me :-)). The *reference* to the object is constant, but not the object itself. You can change its properties and even delete them as you will.

Comment: `const` in Javascript is just like `final` in Java, for that matter.

Comment: May be possible in browser but most linters will deny this for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const colors = {
  green: 'yes',
  red: 'no',
  yellow: 'yes'
}

let result = {}
Object.keys(colors).map((key) => { if(colors[key] == 'yes')  result[key] = colors[key]})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
const colors = {
     green:"yes",
     red:"no",
     yellow:"yes"
}
let filteredColors = {}

let filteredKeys = Object.keys(colors).filter(key => {
    return key==="yes"
})

filteredKeys.map(key => {
    filteredColors[key] = "yes"
})
```